# CAGradientLayer send to back

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, cagradientlayer

I have a `UIViewController` where I create a background gradient with

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    ...
    gradient.frame = frame;
    self.backGradient = gradient;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

it works fine, later I have to send the subview `_selectionFrame` of my view controller  to back:
 (I often need to send the `_selectionFrame` to back and to front, for animation and drawing purpose)

`self` is the viewController:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_selectionFrame];
```

However this sends the `_selectionFrame` behind the `gradient`. I want it just above the gradient but below every other subview. The problem is that the gradient is not a view, so i cannot use the functions for the gradient.
I would like to call `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:gradient];`

But this does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a view that contains only the gradient

Answer (score 28):

.layer has a sublayers property which is a simple array. So you can insert at any index you want. If you want your new layer to be at the back, just insert it at 0, like this:

```
let newLayer = CALayer() // your layer that you want at the back
view.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: This is the most accurate I think

Comment: this works but does not cover the whole view like in insertSublayer.. :(

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is not to insert the gradient layer as a sublayer of `self.view.layer`. Instead, it should *be* `self.view.layer`. A UIView subclass has a class method `layerClass` that lets you say what class its layer should be.

For example, in your `UIView` subclass you would add this:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
```

And when referencing `self.layer` within the view, wrap it a guard let or if let to convert the type like such:

```
guard let layer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else { ... }
```

Or, it could *be* the layer of some other subview of `self.view`, again easily arranged by using the same class method `layerClass`.

Otherwise, you will have to use layer commands, not view commands, to order the sublayers of `self.view`. That includes its subviews. In other words, if `v` is a subview of `self.view`, then `v.layer` is a sublayer of `self.view.layer` and you can order it among its sublayers by rearranging the sublayers array.

Comment: self.view.layer = self.backGradient; does not works self.view.layer is read only

Comment: You didn't read what I said. You must use a custom UIView and implement `layerClass` so that the UIView is "born" with a CAGradientLayer as its layer.

Comment: Thanks interesting, but more complex than necessary (for me)

Comment: Thank you! this was the only answer that ended up solving this for me.

I think some code examples of this would greatly help in other using this solution, so I'm going to propose an edit with an example

Comment: @bplattenburg Good edit, I just cleaned up the code formatting.